# C# Windows Form App get sales data/transaction details from Paypal using C# SDK?

Tags: c#, winforms, paypal

I currently have a Windows Form App (C#) used to generate tickets for an charity exhibition, currently I have to enter the transaction details in manually (e.g name, number of each ticket sold) and I'm looking for a way to get the transaction data out of paypal pragmatically.

I'm not really a developer (IT technician would be a more apt description), I've got as far as downloading the c# SDK and I think the trasnsactionsearch method may be what I'm looking for, but reading the documentation I really don't understand or have a clue how to get this to work. All I'm really looking to do is connect to paypal and grab the number of each ticket sold and the name of the purchaser so I Can put them in my MySQL database, any help or examples of how to do this would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An intermediate solution would be to go to the History tab and download a date range or full transaction history in CSV format and then import that through your program.  (or even from a generic MySQL console or client if you structure your tables appropriately).  This is probably more the "IT technician" way of doing things, vis a vis implementing the TransactionSearch method.

A going-forward solution might be to implement an Instant Payment Notification (IPN) listener that loads transactions into your database one-by-one the moment they come in.  IPN scripts aren't hard to do and there's plenty of resources out there.

Comment: Thanks, I have used the download history tool for now, will look into IPN